# 2048 Game - Trigger key events in the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, triggers, console, 2048

I'm trying to trigger key events in the Chrome console but nothing seems to work.

I want to trigger any of the arrow keys programmatically (for an experiment).

I've tried this (among many other things)

`window.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {keyCode: 39}))`

The game code is pretty short.

http://2048game.com/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please do not add links to external sites as it is considered a bad practice in SO

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt What's the best practice?

Comment: @gatzkerob creating an [MCVE]